# Role based authentication with Springboot

Tags: rest, spring-security, spring-boot

I am pretty new to springboot and I have been having issues using the role based basic authentication on some of my methods. I have written a custom UserDetailsService which works fine without roles.

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String arg0)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Developer d = DeveloperFactory.loadDeveloperByQuery(" Email = '" + arg0 + "'", null);
        if (d == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException ("User with email " + arg0 + " doesn't exist in our database");

        String username = d.getEmail();
        String password = d.getPassword();
        boolean enabled = d.getActive ();
        boolean accountNonExpired = enabled; 
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = enabled;
        boolean accountNonLocked = enabled;

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(Role role : d.roles.toArray()) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        UserDetails u = new User (username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        return u;
    }

Once I add a role with the @Secured annotation to my controller methods like

    @Secured({"USER"})
        @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public Developer[] getByQuery (@RequestParam(value="email", required=false) String email) { 
            if (email == null) {
                Developer[] admins = DeveloperFactory.listDeveloperByQuery(" IsAdmin = TRUE", null);
                return admins;
            } else {
                Developer admin = DeveloperFactory.loadDeveloperByQuery("Email = '" + email + "'", null);
                if (admin == null) throw new AdminNotFound ();
                return new Developer[]{admin};
            }
        }
```

I start to get the forbidden error. I confirmed the users have the roles requested in database, but still wont work. My SecurityConfigurer looks like this.

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(new UserDetailsServiceImpl());
        }

        @Override
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() {
            return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
        }


    }
```

and my application class like this.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }    
}
```

Can someone please tell my why my user roles are not being applied on the /admin GET endpoint?

Here are my logs.

```
2014-06-06 03:16:04.453 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2014-06-06 03:16:04.454 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2014-06-06 03:16:04.454 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-06-06 03:23:04.886 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.886 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.886 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.887 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@68fe414e
2014-06-06 03:23:04.887 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.887 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/admin'; against '/logout'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.887 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.887 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.888 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.888 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.889 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.889 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-06-06 03:23:04.889 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /admin reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2014-06-06 03:23:04.894 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public com.withinet.cloud.domain.Developer[] com.withinet.cloud.service.AdminController.getByQuery(java.lang.String); target is of class [com.withinet.cloud.service.AdminController]; Attributes: [ROLE_WEB]
2014-06-06 03:23:04.894 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2014-06-06 03:23:04.894 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@7bcf60f2, returned: -1
2014-06-06 03:23:04.894 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@6be5ef5e, returned: 0
2014-06-06 03:23:04.896 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at com.withinet.cloud.service.AdminController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7633a4cc.getByQuery(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2014-06-06 03:23:04.897 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
2014-06-06 03:23:04.897 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2014-06-06 03:23:04.897 DEBUG 9364 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You normally need "ROLE_" prefix in `@Secured` (if you want to use the role voter), i.e. `@Secured("ROLE_USER")`.

Comment: Hi Dave, an Update. My POST, DELETE, and PUT methods aren't working with the roles except GET. Is there a difference between GET and the other methods in this context or are my just missing something. I have annotated them with the same role as mentioned.

Comment: Look at the debug logs. You probably have CSRF enabled (or something) and your client isn't including the token.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It still doesn't work after disabling csrf like this. @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable();
    }

Comment: That's why I suggested looking at the logs. DEBUG logs will tell you what the 403 is about (or there might even be a WWW-Authenticate header).

Comment: I started the app with --debug argument but I don't see the requests being debugged in console. basically nothing changes after startup.

Comment: You need to enable DEBUG logging explicitly on org.springframework.security (e.g. with a custom logback.xml). Example: [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure/src/main/resources/logback.xml).

Comment: I just updated the Question with the logs. why does the request use the ROLE_ANONYMOUS in the logs?

Comment: Another question, does configure(HttpSecurity http) override the @Secured annotations behaviour?

Comment: extended problems solved. I just figured I had to include httpbasic () method in the httpsecurity configuration like http.csrf().disable().httpBasic(); Thanks for your help @Dave

Comment: @DaveSyer i have worked in XML based spring security configuration where we used to manually define which accessDecisionManager we want to use like `AffirmativeBased`. similarly for decisionVoters like `RoleVoter`. I know Spring boot is opinionated but is there a document or link which defines what spring boot use by default ?

Comment: The default decision manager is provided by Spring Security. Maybe check the user guide (failing that source code).